# Can't access file in subdirectory with os.walk()?

Tags: python

Here is the code to open shapefiles in the subfolders:

```
import geopandas

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\psiharis\Desktop\a'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".shp")):
            gpd.read_file(name)
```

it gives:

```
OSError: no such file or directory: 'uk.shp'
```

which means that it needs to also put one step in the directory to work.

Imagine this:
main folder:

```
f1/uk/uk.shp
```

what it reads is:

```
f1/uk.shp
```

how to make it insert also the uk folder that contains the .shp?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
import geopandas
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\psiharis\Desktop\a'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".shp")):
            gpd.read_file(name/name)# to put the extra folder with the same name
```

Comment: What happens when you use "\\" instead of "\"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant replace the single backslashes by double ones: backslashes sometimes are wildcard characters which change the meaning of the next character.

Comment: Same thing. A fix would be to remove the `.shp` extension from the path. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: It looks correct to me, are you sure that the variable `name` can be used (just print it and check the content)?

Comment: name has the final file name with the extension with it.It needs the rest of the path too maybe??

Comment: Why do you use double brackets around that `endswith()`?

Comment: I removed the extra but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import geopandas
import os 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\psiharis\Desktop\a'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".shp")):
            gpd.read_file(os.path.join(root, name))
```

This has to work.

Comment: this is way better but how can it read all the subfolders in that main folder that each contains an shp? I want to read each subfolder that has an shp extension and assign it to a new variable. But, If a subfolder doesn't have an shp to say the name  of the subfolder and that is doesn't have an shp.